# Remover Espaço Duplicado no Meio da String

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá,
Preciso remover espaços duplicados em uma string e deixar somente 1, identico a funcao arrumar do Excel. 
Como fazer isso no sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Conceitos Básicos**

Trim: Retira todos os espaços em branco independente da posição (Esquerda ou Direita) do campo desejado.
Ltrim: Retira os espaços em branco que estão à esquerda do campo desejado.
Rtrim: Retira os espaços em branco que estão à direita do campo desejado.

**Exemplos:


1 - Como retirar os espaços em branco excedentes do seguinte texto:**

```
'  Papo Sql - Retirando espaços em Branco  '
 Select Trim(' Papo Sql - Retirando espaços em Branco ');  
 Results  
 'Papo Sql - Retirando espaços em Branco'
```

Perceba que, os espaços que haviam à direita e esquerda foram eliminados, vejamos a próxima situação.

**2 - Como retirar os espaços em branco excedentes do seguinte texto:**

```
'  Papo Sql - Retirando espaços em Branco à esquerda de um campo  '
 Select LTrim('  Papo Sql - Retirando espaços em Branco a esquerda de um campo  ');  
 Results  
 'Papo Sql - Retirando espaços em Branco a esquerda de um campo   '
```

Neste caso, ainda temos espaços à direita, porém, a função cumpriu com o proposto, retirar os espaços à esquerda, agora:

**3 - Como retirar os espaços em branco excedentes do seguinte texto:**

```
'  Papo Sql - Retirando espaços em Branco à direita de um campo  '
 Select RTrim(' Papo Sql - Retirando espaços em Branco a direita de um campo '); 
 Results  
 ' Papo Sql - Retirando espaços em Branco a direita de um campo'
```

Desta vez, temos o inverso da situação anterior, retirando os espaços à direita.

Voltando ao assunto inicial, quando você for inserir as informações no banco de dados, utilize as funções, evitando assim que os campos do tipo texto tenha espaços desnecessários.

Agora, quando o banco já contiver espaços em branco, a eliminação deve ocorrer com o uso do Update, utilizando o Trim, Ltrim ou o Rtrim, dependendo da sua situação, vejamos o exemplo:

```
 Update tabela  
 Set nome = Trim(nome);
```

Neste exemplo retiramos todos os espaços à direita e esquerda da coluna nome.

[FONTE](http://paposql.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/como-retirar-espacos-em-branco.html)

Comment: Bem legal. Eu sabia que existia a função Trim, porém desconhecia essa LTrim e RTrim.. ela esta presente em todos os bancos relacionais?

Comment: Nos que testei (SQLite, MySQL, Oracle) funcionou.